# What is wrong with my Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javascript to test for the ending of a file that is selected to be uploaded to the server.

The regex is this:

`(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$`

And it works fine as long as the file extensions are in lower case, but when I do this

`/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/i`

I doesn't match anything.

Can someone tell me why? What am I doing that is wrong?

Comment: Drop that and use server-side file-header tests to determine the type of file instead. For starters, clients without JavaScript can get past this filter trivially, nowithstanding the ability for people to just change malicious filenames to .jpg when it's really something else.

Comment: It will be validated more thoroughly on the server, just is just to let the user know ahead of time.

Comment: @Welbog: As you say, testing on the client provides *no security*. However, it does enhance usability: you tell the (non-malicious) user that their large image file is invalid *before* they've spent ten seconds waiting for it to upload.

Comment: For example, someone who tries to upload a 30MB RAW image file will be told no, and they won't have to wait a year or two for their dialup connection to tell them the server rejected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use 'i' as parameter
i.e. RegExp("(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$", "i")

Comment: in JS, he might just write `var regexp = /expression/i;`, FYI

Answer (score 2):

```
/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/i
```

You should probably include the `.` in there too, so that *"foo.dfpng"*, *"bar.oejpg"* etc don't count as valid:

```
/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

Use forward slashes as the boundaries of your regex, not backslashes.

```
/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

the slashes are wrong. Reverse them (need forward slash). Backward slashes are used for escaping characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's sample code that works, using both regexp syntaxes:

```
var rxp = new RegExp('(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$', 'i')
var rxp2 = /(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/i
document.write( rxp.exec('foo.jpg') + "<br/>" )
document.write( rxp.exec('foo.JPG') + "<br/>" )
document.write( rxp2.exec('foo.jpg') + "<br/>" )
document.write( rxp2.exec('foo.JPG') + "<br/>" )
```

Answer (score 0):

this works..

```
var reg=/(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$/i
document.write(reg.test('bMp'))
```